# check database in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, jsp

I am working on project based on jsp and servlet and in that, on 1 of the page there is an option(dropdown list).In that I want to check if the current selected value is in database or not.Currently it works but when I click a button button but I want to check whenever the value from dropdown list changes.

Example-

```
<select id="abc">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Now for javascript I did-

```
<script> 
var e = document.getElementById("abc");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
</script>
```

Now how do I check this str value in database in jsp??

I think it can be done by javascript but not sure and also don't know how to check value from database in script tag.It might be ajax also please help

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using AJAX and PHP.

First, you need to do a POST to your back-end containing the data in the fields you want to check against:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.yourbackend.php",
    data: {
             username: username,
             password: password
    },
    success: function(data){}
});
```

Then you need to query whether the value exists on your back-end script. If you're using PHP with PDO for example, it would look something like:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name');
$query->bindParam(':name', $_POST['username']);
$query->execute();
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->rowCount() > 0));
```

(In this example, `username` is queried).

Whether the value exists or not will be assigned to JavaScript's `data` return, which you can use however you'd like. It's up to you to process it from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In that case it helps to tag your question as `jsp` rather than just `database`.